# Use Apps Script to change the response of a single form item directly (programmatically) rather than using the edit response urlj

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using a form to collect booking details and have the script attached to the form (so that the form submit trigger will trigger when the response is edited, which the spreadsheet bound version does not allow) which sends an email, schedules calendar events, creates confirmation documents etc on form submit. Using if statements I have provided the user the ability to avoid 'click the box to not send the customer an email on submit' functionality so that the form responses can be edited without triggers the automated functions, but that relies on the user remembering to click those boxes.
A better solution would be to be able to have the script, as its final function, change the item response, so that when the form is edited in future, the automatic functions are already disabled.

I do not want to create a new form response (although it would be possible to tweak the pre-populated url to create a duplicate with the appropriate changes)

FormResponse.withItemResponse(response) specifies that it doesn't work on stored responses

It is so easy to view form responses, and with the native edit response url functionality I figured editing a single item response would be doable, but so far it has eluded me.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think you could provide a link to an example form (with script would help) and its corresponding spreadsheet so it is easier to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1):

At this time Form responses could only be created programmatically, they can't be edited programmatically. Consider to submit a feature request through [Google Apps Script Issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/l)